# Why doesn't Get-NetFirewallRule show all information of the firewall rule? (like netsh)

Tags: powershell, windows-firewall

I'm trying to find if a firewall rule already existing, with the same name, same configuration, like: localport.

So I use `Get-NetFirewallRule` to list all rules, but the rules returned do not contain the information of port, also some other information are missing. where can I find all the config of a rule. Below is the attributess returned:

```
Name
DisplayName
Description
DisplayGroup
Group
Enabled
Profile
Platform
Direction
Action
EdgeTraversalPolicy
LooseSourceMapping
LocalOnlyMapping
Owner
PrimaryStatus
Status
EnforcementStatus
PolicyStoreSource
PolicyStoreSourceType
```

Answer (score 9):

What I don't think is understood by many, including me recently, is that the Get-NetFirewall*Filter commands provide a speedy shortcut to searching the firewall rules, like the -filter option does in other commands.  If I were to do this, it would take a very long time:

```
Get-NetFirewallRule | Get-NetFirewallPortFilter | 
  Where LocalPort -eq 3389
```

While this is almost instant:

```
Get-NetFirewallPortFilter | Where LocalPort -eq 3389
```

And Get-NetFirewallPortFilter actually returns the name of the firewall rule in the InstanceID property, which isn't shown by default.  That's why you can pipe Get-NetFirewallPortFilter back into Get-NetFirewallRule.

```
Get-NetFirewallPortFilter | Where LocalPort -eq 3389 |
  Get-NetFirewallRule
```

Here's a function that gives netsh-like verbose output, with the ports, addresses, and applications:

```
function mynetsh {
  param($displayname)

  # in case there's more than one with wildcards
  get-netfirewallrule -displayname $displayname | foreach {
    $rule = $_

    $address = $rule | Get-NetFirewallAddressFilter
    $port = $rule | Get-NetFirewallPortFilter
    $application = $rule | Get-NetFirewallApplicationFilter
    [pscustomobject]@{
      DisplayName = $rule.DisplayName
      Description = $rule.Description  
      Enabled = $rule.Enabled
      Direction = $rule.Direction
      Profile = $rule.Profile
      DisplayGroup = $rule.DisplayGroup
      LocalAddress = $address.LocalAddress
      RemoteAddress = $address.RemoteAddress
      Protocol = $port.Protocol
      LocalPort = $port.LocalPort
      RemotePort = $port.RemotePort
      EdgeTraversalPolicy = $rule.EdgeTraversalPolicy
      Program = $application.Program 
      Action = $rule.Action
    }
  }  # end foreach
} # end function

mynetsh 'Remote Desktop - User Mode (TCP-In)'

DisplayName         : Remote Desktop - User Mode (TCP-In)
Description         : Inbound rule for the Remote Desktop service to allow RDP traffic. [TCP 3389]
Enabled             : False
Direction           : Inbound
Profile             : Any
DisplayGroup        : Remote Desktop
LocalAddress        : Any
RemoteAddress       : Any
Protocol            : TCP
LocalPort           : 3389
RemotePort          : Any
EdgeTraversalPolicy : Block
Program             : %SystemRoot%\system32\svchost.exe
Action              : Allow
```

Comment: Wish I could upvote this more than once. Thank you for the clear information, code examples, and coverage of the topic. Excellent post.

Answer (score 4):

In order to find the port numbers that are already in the firewall rules, you can use a different cmdlet `Get-NetFirewallPortFilter`.

([Info](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj573829))

Use `Get-NetFirewallRule` to filter which subset of rules you want to look at and pipe it to the above cmdlet.  eg.:

```
Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "SQL Broker Service" | Get-NetFirewallPortFilter
```

Sounds like the property you are after is localport.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below command to list all.

```
Get-NetFirewallRule| Where { $_.Enabled -eq $True } |
Format-Table -Property Name,
DisplayName,
DisplayGroup,
@{Name='Protocol';Expression={($PSItem | Get-NetFirewallPortFilter).Protocol}},
@{Name='LocalPort';Expression={($PSItem | Get-NetFirewallPortFilter).LocalPort}},
@{Name='RemotePort';Expression={($PSItem | Get-NetFirewallPortFilter).RemotePort}},
@{Name='RemoteAddress';Expression={($PSItem | Get-NetFirewallAddressFilter).RemoteAddress}},
Enabled,
Profile,
Direction,
Action
```

The output is shown below 
[image]

Comment: I just wanted to edit out the ">> " stuff.  But weirdly, sometimes 'True' doesn't work and $True does.  Sometimes Enabled is an interger, and sometimes it's an Enum.

Comment: This looks to be the source of the above answer: https://itluke.online/2018/11/27/how-to-display-firewall-rule-ports-with-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

Use the Select-Object Cmdlet to Display all Properties

This will Display only the First one so you dont get flooded with text, feel free to delete the "-First 1" as needed

```
Get-NetFirewallRule | select -First 1 -Property *
```

However investigating that it does not seem like there is Information about the port, looking further into it - you would probably need to use Get-NetFirewallPortFilter and match them up by instanceid. If you need help with that I'll need a little more Information on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Great, Fabian ! Actrually I am using powershell add a firewall rule like this: netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="MyService" protocol=TCP dir=in localport=8009 action=allow. So I need to check if there is already a rule named "MyService" existing. And you know in the firewall rules there may be duplicated name rules. So I need to check the specific configuration, like port. To make sure I add a different rule.

Answer (score 0):

If you use only the firewall cmdlets to get a list of object that include ports, programs etc., it's not an easy task, and it's very slow! Why not try the old school way, the `netsh advfirewall firewall` command suite. Below is my trying to get a list of objects that include all rule information.

```
$output = (netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=all verbose | Out-String).Trim() -split '\r?\n\s*\r?\n'
$propertyNames = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()

$objects = @( $(foreach($section in $output ) {
    $obj = @{}
    foreach( $line in ($section -split '\r?\n') ) {
        if( $line -match '^\-+$' ) { continue }
        $name, $value = $line -split ':\s*', 2
        $name = $name -replace " ", ""
        
        $obj.$name  = $value
        if($propertyNames -notcontains $name) {
            $propertyNames.Add( $name )
        }
    }
    $obj
}) | % {
    foreach( $prop in $propertyNames ) {
        if( $_.Keys -notcontains $prop ) {
            $_.$prop = $null
        }
    }
    [PSCustomObject]$_
})
```