# which command that lists all the firewall rules on a system with the output containing the information and headers : Rule name, TCP port, Enabled?

Tags: powershell, firewall

I have been trying to get only specific data from the firewall rules in powershell. The command i tried is **Get-NetFirewallRule | select DisplayName, Enabled**, but it does not output required one.

Comment: I talk about the firewall filter commands here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42110526/why-doesnt-get-netfirewallrule-show-all-information-of-the-firewall-rule/58138487#58138487

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this (It's a bit slow):

```
$rules = Get-NetFirewallRule
$rules | Foreach {
    $rule = (Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName $_.DisplayName | Get-NetFirewallPortFilter)
    If($rule.Protocol -eq "TCP"){
      [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Rule Name' = $_.DisplayName
        'TCP Port' = $rule.LocalPort
        'Enabled' = $_.Enabled
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. II have a small question , Is there any direct command without declaring variable? Like in this case $rules has been assigned. For the required output is it necessary to assign a variable first and do the rest?

Comment: No, you can do `(Get-NetFirewallRule)` in place of `$rules` inside Foreach loop

Comment: Alright.. Thank You. Helped a lot!!

Comment: If this helped then please click on the big tick mark to accept it as answer of this question. Welcome