Create rule with New-NetFirewallRule and get LocalPort value of the rule created
When creating Windows Firewall rule with New-NetFirewallRule, it returns some data about rule created:
PS C:\> New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Allow debug rule" -Direction inbound -Profile Any -Action Allow -LocalPort 3333 -Protocol UDP -RemoteAddress 127.0.0.2


Name                  : {2326a022-fake-mock-fake-636ec5f615b9}
DisplayName           : Allow debug rule
Description           :
DisplayGroup          :
Group                 :
Enabled               : True
Profile               : Any
Platform              : {}
Direction             : Inbound
Action                : Allow
EdgeTraversalPolicy   : Block
LooseSourceMapping    : False
LocalOnlyMapping      : False
Owner                 :
PrimaryStatus         : OK
Status                : The rule was parsed successfully from the store. (65536)
EnforcementStatus     : NotApplicable
PolicyStoreSource     : PersistentStore
PolicyStoreSourceType : Local

I could select from this returned data and get some fields values (e.g. Name, DisplayName, Action, Direction), but can't get LocalPort value since it is not returned. E.g.:
PS C:\> New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Allow debug rule" -Direction inbound -Profile Any -Action Allow -LocalPort 3333 -Protocol UDP -RemoteAddress 127.0.0.2 | select Name, DisplayName, Enabled, Action, Direction


Name        : {2326a022-fake-mock-fake-636ec5f615b9}
DisplayName : Allow debug rule
Enabled     : True
Action      : Allow
Direction   : Inbound

How could I get LocalPort value for the new rule just created with New-NetFirewallRule?

Here's a netsh-like powershell function:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/58138487/6654942

Pipe the rule object to the appropriate(*) Get-NetFirewall*Filter cmdlet to get the associated filters:
PS ~> $newRule = New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Allow debug rule" -Direction inbound -Profile Any -Action Allow -LocalPort 3333 -Protocol UDP -RemoteAddress 127.0.0.2
PS ~> $newRule |Get-NetFirewallPortFilter

Protocol      : UDP
LocalPort     : 3333
RemotePort    : Any
IcmpType      : Any
DynamicTarget : Any

PS ~> $newRule |Get-NetFirewallAddressFilter

LocalAddress  : Any
RemoteAddress : 127.0.0.2

PS ~>


You can use Get-Command to list the relevant cmdlets for getting the filters:
PS ~> Get-Command Get-NetFirewall*Filter

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Function        Get-NetFirewallAddressFilter                       2.0.0.0    NetSecurity
Function        Get-NetFirewallApplicationFilter                   2.0.0.0    NetSecurity
Function        Get-NetFirewallInterfaceFilter                     2.0.0.0    NetSecurity
Function        Get-NetFirewallInterfaceTypeFilter                 2.0.0.0    NetSecurity
Function        Get-NetFirewallPortFilter                          2.0.0.0    NetSecurity
Function        Get-NetFirewallSecurityFilter                      2.0.0.0    NetSecurity
Function        Get-NetFirewallServiceFilter                       2.0.0.0    NetSecurity

